# Returning d3 SVG HTML in PhantomJS

Tags: d3.js, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS + d3 to render SVG on the server. I'm able to return the HTML of the entire body of the page with the d3-created SVG inside, but if I try to return just the SVG then I get back `null`.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.content = '<html><body></body></html>';

page.includeJs('http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js', function() {
    var html = page.evaluate(function() {
        var body = d3.select('body');
        var svg = body.append('svg');
        svg.append('rect');
        svg.append('circle');
        return body.html();
    });
    console.log(html);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Returns `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script><svg><rect></rect><circle></circle></svg>`.

But if I change `return body.html()` to `return svg.html()`, `null` is returned.

I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.8 and d3.v3.js. Any ideas on why I can't select out just the svg?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, I can now answer my own question: SVG does not support innerHTML so d3's `.html()` won't work. From the [d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#html):

> Note: as its name suggests, selection.html is only supported on HTML elements. SVG elements and other non-HTML elements do not support the innerHTML property, and thus are incompatible with selection.html. Consider using XMLSerializer to convert a DOM subtree to text. See also the innersvg polyfill, which provides a shim to support the innerHTML property on SVG elements.

Using XMLSerializer solves the issue:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.content = '<html><body></body></html>';

page.includeJs('http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js', function() {
    var html = page.evaluate(function() {
        var body = d3.select('body');
        var svg = body.append('svg');
        svg.append('rect');
        svg.append('circle');
        var s = new XMLSerializer();
        return s.serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));
    });
    console.log(html);
    phantom.exit();
});
```